# About a book on integral calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am currently a second year undergraduate student in mathematics; I am taking Integral Calculus, however I have run into a difficulty.

This is the discomfort that some books of integral calculus generate in me, for the moment I am using Spivak's book of infinitesimal calculus, however I want to know which books you recommend me to strengthen my learning of integral calculus. This taking into account that the book should be focused on mathematicians.

Thanks

Comment: What is the nature of your discomfort ?

Comment: Well, starting with the fact that my current teacher only uses this book, some questions in my exams are not properly taken from spivak, so in order to broaden my knowledge I am looking for a book that complements the above mentioned.

Comment: You have to say what kind of complements, is is the rigor of the proofs or is it techniques of integration, what is missing from your knowledge ?

Comment: Especially the rigor of the tests, I feel that I find it difficult to tackle some exercises in my exams.

Comment: It would help a lot in answering this question if you could give an example of a question you find hard.

Comment: It is difficult to define my interest with a particular exercise, however an example might be the following. Prove that $\int_x^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} $=$\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}}$. I usually hesitate at what point to do a test with the infimum, minimum or the partitions of an interval.

Comment: Spivak is an excellent text. A very slight variant of this very exercise is in there. Your hesitations seem all wrong, however. Either do a substitution in the integral or use the first fundamental theorem of calculus to differentiate. Maybe you need to do more concrete problems and not so many proofs in Spivak?

Comment: It is my guess that you are struggling with the change in emphasis from a first year course in calculus, targeted to techniques of integration, to an emphasis on rigor in  the theory of integration in a class for math majors.  But the example you gave doesn't illustrate that, so perhaps I'm jumping to a wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is my view on calculus books. The best book on calculus is Fichtenholz, Differential und Integralrechnung. It is 3volumes. The original is russian, and it has been translated into german and polish.  It is solid and rigorous exposition of all issues in calculus with many examples.

Another classic book is Joseph Edwards, Treatise on Integral Calculus 2vols. It is in english and can be found online on internet archive. It is very extensive on examples and methods of integration, but it does not cover theoretical aspects.
He also has Integral Calculus for Beginners, a smaller and more approachable book. And has books on Differential calculus.

Another traditional text is Todhunter, Treatise on Integral Calculus, and Treatise on Differential Calculus, less extensive than Edwards, but easier to assimilate.

The modern text for rigorous calulus is Rudin, Principles or Real Analysis. Solid proofs of the theory, although using topological concepts, but weak on examples.

Another good book is Philip Franklin, Treatise on Advanced Calculus.

Looking at your example, it is more of a practical question and not so much theoretical, I recommend Todhunter, or Edwards, Integral Calculus for Beginners whichever you find better.

Of course, this list betrays my preference for older books.
Finally, one cannot become an expert in any subject by reading one book no matter how good it is, you must read several.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is very useful